# R Caret: NA Errors when there is no missing value

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, glmnet

I am attempting to run a classification algorithm for a dataset with no missing values. Here is the dataset description:

```
'data.frame':   59977 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ gender      : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ age         : num  35.7 35.7 35.7 35.7 35.7 ...
 $ code        : Factor w/ 492 levels "ADN105","AXN16B",..: 128 128 128 363 363 363 104 104 221 221 ...
 $ totalflags  : num  4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 2 2 ...
 $ measure2    : num  30 30 30 1 1 1 23 23 22 22 ...
 $ outcome     : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:138] 3718 3719 5493 5494 5495 5496 7302 7303 8415 8416 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:138] "4929" "4930" "7384" "7385" ...
```

When I run the following command

```
x <- Mydataset[,1:5]
y <- Mydataset[,6]
fit <- glmnet(x, y, family="binomial", alpha=0.5, lambda=0.001)
```

I get

```
Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
In addition: Warning message:
In lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Before running the glm model, I did this:

```
Mydataset <- na.omit(Mydataset)
```

And checked to make sure no NA's exist:

```
sapply(Mydataset, function(y) sum(length(which(is.na(y)))))
```

and I got:

```
gender          age       code totalflags     measure2   outcome


 0            0            0            0            0            0
```

I looked at other questions for couldn't find anything relevant. Appreciate any thoughts and help in this

**EDIT: ANSWER**

I did a little digging and decided to change the data frame to numeric matrix and the model ran without complaining. This is the code that helped me:

```
x <- data.matrix(Mydataset[,1:5])
y <- data.matrix(Mydataset[,6])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858124/r-error-in-glmnet-na-nan-inf-in-foreign-function-call

Comment: I see someone commenting that they get the same error without any NA values but no solution is available for their comment. My dataset has no NA values at all.

Comment: So you checked for NA but the error message said one of `NA/NaN/Inf`. A common reason for Inf is division by 0 and a common reason for NaN is log(0). You should also refactor the `na.omit`-ted dataframe to remove an non-existent levels.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is small or zero numbers of factor variables within one or more levels. Try this first:

```
 Mydataset [ c('gender',  'code') ] <- 
                             lapply( Mydataset [ c('gender',  'code') ], factor)
```

If that's not effective then you should show the actual code used and better description and names of all objects used. At the moment we don't even know what are `x` and `y`.

`EDIT:` The glmnet function does not have a formula interface and is not set up to handle data.frames and factors the way that typical R regression functions would allow. After looking at the structure of `x` (still a list/dataframe) and reviewing the help page for `?glmnet` and doing a bit of searching for the correct way to handle factors when a numeric *matrix* is the expected input, I suggest converting your factors to dummies with `model.matrix`. It's going to be easier for interpretation of the results if you change the default contrast scheme for treatment contrasts (See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69804/group-categorical-variables-in-glmnet):

```
contr.Dummy <- function(contrasts, ...){
   conT <- contr.treatment(contrasts=FALSE, ...)
   conT
}
options(contrasts=c(ordered='contr.Dummy', unordered='contr.Dummy'))

x.m <- model.matrix( ~.-1, x)
fit <- glmnet(x=x.m, y, family="binomial", alpha=0.5, lambda=0.001)
```

Comment: Hi @42-, apologies, made a typo in my answer -- I used data.matrix(Mydataset) and not data.frame(Mydataset).